# Java-flavoured Regex : Match whole string if group is n chars

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to create a Regex for a String validator. My String must be exactly 8 characters long, and begin with a letter (lowercase or uppercase) or a number. It can only contain letters (lowercase and uppercase), numbers or whitespaces right after that first character. If a whitespace is found, there can only be whitespaces after it.

For now, I have the match group for the second part : `[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}\s*`

I can't find a way to specify that this group is matched only if it has exactly 8 characters. I tried `^([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}\s*){8}$` but this is not the expected result.

Here are some test cases (with trailing whitespaces).

**Valid :**

```
9013    
20130   
89B     
A5000000
```

**Invalid :**

```
9013     
 20130  
90 90   
123456789
```

Comment: How is `9013` a valid input as it is only 4 char long

Comment: if string must be **exactly** 8 characters long, then why are 9013, 20130 and 89B valid?

Comment: @anubhava there are 4 spaces at the end

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this lookahead based regex:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9](?!.* [a-zA-Z0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9 ]{7}$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hW9sG6/1)

- `^[a-zA-Z0-9]` matches an alpha-num char at start
- `(?!.* [a-zA-Z0-9])` is negative lookahead to make sure that there is no instance of an alpha-num char followed by a space.
- `[a-zA-Z0-9 ]{7}$` matches 7 chars containing alpha-num char  or space.

Answer (score 5):

There probably is a smart regex way to do it but you could also first check the length of the string:

```
input.length() == 8 && input.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\s*")
```

This is also probably more efficient than a complex regex.

Comment: Since you check the length before, you can change `{1,8}` to `+`.

Comment: I don't think there's any "smart" regular expression that could beat the simplicity of de-coupling global length and sequence requirements.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm using an out-of-the-box enterprise "tool" (spring batch tasklet) which can only take a regex as an argument. Otherwise, your solution would have been easier, thanks anyway!